# Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : there is no package called 'stringi'

Tags: r, ggplot2, hmisc, stringi

When I use

```
library(Hmisc)
```

I get the following error

```
    Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : there is no package called 'stringi'
    Error: package 'ggplot2' could not be loaded
```

As well, if I use

```
library(ggplot2)
```

I get the following error

```
    Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : there is no package called 'stringi'
    Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2'
```

I've tryed to install 'stringi'
    install.packages("stringi")

But at some point, during the installation, I get the following error message:

```
    configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/pr/wdr5dvjj24bb4wwnjpg1hndc0000gr/T/RtmpeQ5pXk/R.INSTALL10b94a012cab/stringi':
    configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
    See `config.log' for more details
    ERROR: configuration failed for package 'stringi'
    * removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/stringi'
```

I'm using RStudio (Version 0.99.447) and I have R version 3.2.1.

Comment: It might help if you provided the output from `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: `apt-get install build-essential` | `yum install gcc` | [download Xcode + run it once to accept license] `xcode-select --install` (OS X)

Comment: @hrbrmstr, out of curiosity, how can you tell that the OP is using OS X and not another flavor of *nix? Are the file paths OS X specific?

Comment: @RichardErickson I cannot. Hence providing Debian/Ubuntu | RedHat/CentOS | OS X  solutions depending on OP's setup.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, okay. I understand your comment now. Thanks for answering my question. I agree that OS is needed to provide an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: ARGH! @RichardErickson, the OP is using OS X. The `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/` gives that away. Marta: Grab Xcode from the Mac App Store and use that `xcode-select --install` to download the command line tools. You may need a (free) developer account.

Comment: I think this is exacly the same case as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/31038636/168747. R tries to install package from sources cause source is newer than binary (0.5-2 vs 0.4-1). Set `options(install.packages.check.source = "no")` and then `install.packages("stringi")`. (IMPORTANT: it's related to new releases of package, now everything should be ok)

Answer (score 18):

I got this error while trying to load the **swirl package**.

You can try to re install the package directly from cran and include an argument to ensure all the dependant packages are included.

```
install.packages("swirl", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
install.packages("package_name", repos=c("http://rstudio.org/_packages",
"http://cran.rstudio.com",dependencies=TRUE))
```

This works as it assigns from where to download the package.

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: Use this:

`install.packages("package name", dependencies = TRUE)'