# I can't knit HTML on R Markdown. Can anyone please assist?

Tags: r, rstudio

The error that I get is:

```
processing file: 1.Rmd
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'stringi'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I've tried installing the `stringi` package and loading it using the library function. But I still get the error.

I use R Studio Version 0.99.441 on on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: you probably used the package in your rmarkdown-file, so you need to load inside the document you are trying to knit

Comment: `install.package("stringi")` ?

Comment: I tried using your method but it does not seem to work. If still can't knit an HTML file on R Markdown. I tried installing string on both my console in R Studio and my R Markdown document. Do you know any other way?

Comment: Can you see whether your code chunks run in the console?

Comment: I suspect you have the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038636/package-stringi-does-not-work-after-updating-to-r3-2-1 and have been unsuccessful in updating the stringi package because you don't have the tools installed to install the package from source. See the link I posted there. Because your version of MacOs X is rather old, you'll need a legacy version of Xcode.

Comment: Maybe you're running the console from a library, but markdown is using a different library without the packages? I've seen something similar before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering it myself.

I updated my version of OS X and RStudio seems to knitting HTML files perfectly.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

I Just had this same problem but on a windows computer here is how I fixed it:

1. Go to the windows folder where all the `r` packages are stored in when `r` installs a package it states the folder. I copy and pasted that address into windows explorer. (mine ended with `R\win-library\3.2`)
2. Delete the folder `stringi` (which is essentially deleting the package `stringi`)
3. Re-install `stringi` using install.packages('stringi')

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total nube (two days of actual R experience) but this is what I did to solve this problem.

I went to packages -> install -> stringi & stringr

Click on the "Install dependencies box"

Make sure that after you install these packages to click the check box on the stringi and stringr boxes under the "Packages" tab.

> require both the stringi and stringr

I would suggest that you just test it in the Console section before you try to do anything else.