# Error loading ggplot2 in RStudio

Tags: r, windows, ggplot2, rstudio

I saw a version of this question posted, but still did not see the answer. I am trying to use ggplot2 but get the following errors

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘stringi’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

I installed stringi - leading to this error

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is
later:
        binary source needs_compilation
stringi  0.5-2  0.5-5              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
 trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/stringi_0.5-2.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
 cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
 cannot open URL    'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/stringi_0.5-2.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘stringi’ failed
```

Then I read this question - [package 'stringi' does not work after updating to R3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038636/package-stringi-does-not-work-after-updating-to-r3-2-1). And followed the suggestion of using the option and getting binaries for my windows version

```
> options(install.packages.check.source = "no")
> install.packages("stringi",type="win.binary")
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/stringi_0.5-2.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/stringi_0.5-2.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘stringi’ failed
```

And now my analysis is stuck just because of this; no ggplot2.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] gridExtra_0.9.1 scales_0.2.5    lattice_0.20-31

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.11.6      digest_0.6.8     plyr_1.8.3       gtable_0.1.2    
[5] proto_0.3-10     tools_3.2.0      munsell_0.4.2    colorspace_1.2-6
[9] knitr_1.10.5
```

Comment: Have you tried a different mirror to download from?

Comment: I did. Still persisting. However, when I added `install.packages("stringi", dependencies = TRUE)` - works now.