# r install.packages error from source

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, install.packages

I need to install packages from source due to the networking siutation I am working in, and I am having problems. I downloaded 'shiny.0.14.2.tar.gz' via a browser from cran (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shiny/index.html), and placed it in my home directory.

In the R console, I typed:

```
install.packages("/home/urwins/shiny_0.14.2.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
```

Which returned the errors:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/urwins/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘shiny’ ...
** package ‘shiny’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
object 'vI' not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘shiny’
* removing ‘/home/urwins/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/shiny’
* restoring previous ‘/home/urwins/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/shiny’
Warning message: 
In install.packages("/home/urwins/shiny_0.14.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL,  :
installation of package ‘/home/urwins/shiny_0.14.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit              status
```

My sessionInfo is:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora 23 (Twenty Three)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
[3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.10.0 markdown_0.7.7    digest_0.6.10     mime_0.5         
[5] jsonlite_1.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.2.0    tools_3.3.1 tcltk_3.3.1
```

I am trying to set-up an open source shiny server via the instructions here (https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/), and the associated Shiny Server Administrative guide.

Comment: Are you using RStudio?

Comment: As suggested by Marek's comment in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983013/error-in-loadnamespacei-clib-loc-libpaths-versioncheck-vii-the), try running `options(install.packages.check.source = "no")` before attempting to install `shiny`.

Comment: @Christoph = No, R.

Comment: @ nrussell = Thanks, I tried that, and then tried installing the package again using the same code and got the following error: 'Error in if (file.size(codeFile) == file.size(loaderFile)) warning("package seems to be using lazy loading already") else { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'