# Not able to get 'memisc' through eeptools in R Studio. No package called memisc while loading eeptools

Tags: r, rstudio, cran

I initially figured memisc comes in eeptools package. So I installed eeptools package.

```
install.packages('eeptools')
```

Then on trying to use memisc

```
library(memisc)
```

I get an error

> Error in library(memisc) : there is no package called ‘memisc’
>   So I try to use eeptools library directly.

```
library(eeptools)
```

Error still extends to this library too...

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[i]]) :    there is no package called ‘memisc’  Show Traceback
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘eeptools’

Based on this problem -  [Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : there is no package called 'stringi'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983013/error-in-loadnamespacei-clib-loc-libpaths-versioncheck-vii-the) 
I tried doing this

```
install.packages("eeptools", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Error still persists. It gave a warning saying it couldn't find memisc.
And I am using R Studio working on an Rmd file, and MacOS, if that helps.

Comment: On my R 3.4.1 in Windows7 the command `install.packages("eeptools", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies=TRUE)` works correctly. I suggest to go to the link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/index.html , to download the package and to install from R using `Install packages from local files`

Comment: That kind of worked. It asked me to update R on doing that it was able to install. Solution - Update R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking @Marco Sandri's suggestion in the comment, I tried installing it manually by downloading the package. It gave an error saying that my R needed to be updated. On updating R the installation of eeptools worked and memisc worked as well.