# Error package or namespace load failed for rminer in loadNamespace

Tags: r

I already installed `rminer` library using `install.packages("rminer")`
I get the following error

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rminer’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘TH.data’
```

I also tried to install with another methods from this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31631013/13610579) but still gave an error.

Im using RStudio 2022.07.2 Build 576 and R version 4.2.1

Comment: Try installing the missing package: `install.packages("TH.data")` and then try reinstalling `install.packages("rminer")`. Either it will work or you should get a different error message.