# My Dataset import returns with an error code

Tags: r, excel, dataset

I tried importing a dataset and it return with this error.

Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
there is no package called ‘cli’

what package do i need to install?

my code read this

personality <- read_xlsx("Downloads/SMP84.xlsx")

Comment: The error message seems to suggest that you need to install the cli package. I don't understand why it was necessary to ask this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983013/error-in-loadnamespacei-clib-loc-libpaths-versioncheck-vii-the

Comment: Welcome Royal Imago! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your next badge. https://stackoverflow.com/tour